# Manage token life time for openID connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I developed an app based on the link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

With OpenID connect, I will be getting the id_token. Based on the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#token-lifetimes where it is mentioned that apps should not be written to expect any of these lifetimes to remain constant. Token lifetimes can and will change at any time.

Can anyone help me to know do with some code sample how to customize the token life times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the token lifetime via directory settings. The feature is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.
But if it is the session duration of your app that you are really after, then I would recommend taking a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/

Comment: Thanks for the response Vittorio  :)